# How can I fix the JSON code error in the attached picture from the code below?

Tags: json

JSON-LD markup generated by Google Structured Data Markup Helper.

error description in image.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWmcy.jpg)

here is my json

```
    <script type= "application/ld+json">
       {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
         "@type" : "Article",
         "headline" : "7 Ways To .........",
         "author" : {
          "@type" : "Person",
          "name" : "xxxxxxxxx",
        },
        "datePublished" : "2017-06-22T08:50",
        "image" : {
        "@type": "imageObject",
         "url":"xxxxx",
       },
        "articleSection" : "Use one of three methods to find the value of the business–cash flow, market or assets. Then boost business value quickly.",
        "url" : "xxxxx",
        "publisher" : {
          "@type" : "Organization",
          "name" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
          "logo": {
          "@type": "imageObject",
          "url": "xxxxxx",  
          }     
      },
      }</script>
```

Comment: Please restructure your post. Not sure where is the start and end of your JSON code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several time extra comma in end of the value.

valid JSON below

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "headline": "7 Ways To .........",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "datePublished": "2017-06-22T08:50",
  "image": {
    "@type": "imageObject",
    "url": "xxxxx"
  },
  "articleSection": "Use one of three methods to find the value of the business–cash flow, market or assets. Then boost business value quickly.",
  "url": "xxxxx",
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "imageObject",
      "url": "xxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```